# Installed mpv with Brew, but nothing in Applications

Tags: macos, video, open-source

I'm trying to play anime with mpv. I have heard that it's the best player for anime.

https://mpv.io/installation/

I go to the website and I see that there's homebrew.

I run `brew install mpv`. It seems to complete successfully. Now what?

There doesn't seem to be an mpv app I can use to open my video files in my /Applications.

Comment: Did you try alternate download link (OS X builds by stolendata): https://laboratory.stolendata.net/~djinn/mpv_osx/mpv-latest.tar.gz

Comment: If `brew install mpv` is complete, run `brew cask install mpv`. .app file should appear in /Applications

Comment: @toma If you want to put an answer, I'd rather you for the checkmark and reputation. You got to the answer faster than I and just had it in the comments.

Comment: @bmike no need, it is not a competition :)

Comment: I love collaborating - especially when everyone sees the credit as shared (via edits or via a tag on the post) - you honed this one down quickly, @toma

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to have the application linked to ~/Applications, have homebrew do that.

```
brew linkapps mpv
```

Since "linkapps" is being removed (for reasons) across all brew recipes, you might instead tap the cask which drops a functioning `mpv` into Applications and runs more like an app than a command line tool.

```
brew install mpv --cask
```

Comment: Brew prints warning for this option: `Warning: 'brew linkapps' has been deprecated and will eventually be removed!`

Comment: Good pointer @toma - I believe the goal is to get all of the packages to self-install when it makes sense. Not sure if `mpv` is fundamentally against that or no one has done that work or if the work is problematic for whatever reason. My guess is a cask would be more appropriate for this tool instead of the two step install and then link.

Comment: As I understand, `brew cask install mpv` is a replacement for `linkapps`. At least I got .app file in my /Applications

Comment: Its not a replacement for `linkapps`. Did not work for `brew cask install terminator`.

Answer (score 11):

Most of the suggestions here no longer work, the current one as of Dec 2020 is:

```
brew install --cask mpv
```

Answer (score 4):

As brew linkapps is now deprecated, the correct way to do this is to use the --with-bundle option when installing mpv.

```
brew install mpv --with-bundle
```

Because you said you have mpv installed with brew already, it's better to **uninstall mpv first** with `brew uninstall mpv --force` After that, run the installation command above.

When the installation is finished, go to your mpv installation folder:

> /usr/local/Cellar/mpv/[version]/

You will see an **mpv.app** in there. Right-click mpv.app > Make Alias. Copy/move the mpv.app alias into your Applications folder. Remove the 'alias' from the filename, so you'll have "mpv.app" in your Applications :)

Reference: mpv formula in homebrew's repository - 
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/mpv.rb#L14

I prefer using --with-bundle rather than cask install as it allows me to use more compile options and to install different versions of mpv (e.g. --HEAD) as opposed to the pre-built package that cask install uses. Hope this helps!

Comment: How do you go to that folder: `/usr/local/` ?

Comment: I figured `Command + Shift + g`.

Comment: `--with-bundle` pulls a bunch of dependencies and builds from source, while the cask formula just downloads the binary which is way quicker in case you don't want to wait for the compilation which might take quite a while.

Comment: Error: invalid option: --with-bundle - any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

Actually an .mpv file is nothing more than a specific format of MPEG2 video. There is nothing specific to Anime in an .MPV file. In fact you can find Anime in a multitude of video formats all over the internet.

Deciding on what is the "best" player for MPV files is more opinion than anything else and Ask Different discourages opinion based questions.

The specific player you have chosen will work fine but would not be *my* (ahem...) first choice as it involves a lot of stuff that is totally unnecessary for playing videos, specifically the installation of Homebrew. Homebrew is very nice but is basically an environment designed for installing Unix-style executables quickly and easily without invoking the use of compilers, shell scripts or other things that many people have no interest in. A bit of overhead for a simple media player.

If all you want to do is play an .mpv file your best bet might be the insanely popular and excellent quality [VLC player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html). It's a direct (web browser link)  download and install and requires nothing more than running the installer in the download. Works a treat and I have been using it successfully for years.

Comment: Nah vlc is garbage. I also already have homebrew as I installed mpv successfully.

Comment: Good points steve - I almost advocated for QuickTime Player in my answer, but I try to presume an OP has good reasons for wanting the specific tool they chose. The cask installs on homebrew are really getting good in my opinion and the fidgety parts where it breaks are getting redesigned so that "it just works" for people not steeped in the shell. +1 in my book for the VLC and discussion on options.

Comment: Ok.. 1) Nobody talked about an "mpv file", 2) the problem with your successful VLC is how fundamentally incredibly slow it is to seek in comparison.